# jquery to hide column from exporting to excel

Tags: php, jquery, excel

How to remove a column made in html from exporting to excel, without hiding the column. I used a custom jquery to export the table into an excel but i want to hide certain columns. Please guide me how can i achieve it

Comment: Show us your code? And what you've tried?

Comment: i tried with this : http://www.splessons.com/2014/06/export-html-table-data-into-excel-using-jquery/#comment-174

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
 myTable.find('#columnHeaderId').css({ "width": "0px" });
```